# Getting error: unable to find library -lveins_inet_dbg when building Simu5G project together with veins for Omnet++

Tags: omnet++, veins, inet

I tried to setup simulation for vehicular networks with Omnet++ and Simu5G.
I followed this instructions (http://simu5g.org/veins_integration.html) but I get building errors when I try to integrate veins in the last step.

**My Specs:**

- OS: Ubuntu 20.04
- Omnet++: v6.0
- inet: v4.4.0
- simu5g: v1.2.0
- veins: v5.2

**The error messages:**

```
Creating shared library: ../out/clang-debug/src/libsimu5g_dbg.so
ld.lld: error: unable to find library -lveins_inet_dbg
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[1]: *** [Makefile:423: ../out/clang-debug/src/libsimu5g_dbg.so] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/user/omnetpp-6.0/Omnetpp_Projects/simu5g/src'
make: *** [Makefile:2: all] Error 2
"make MODE=debug -j2 all" terminated with exit code 2. Build might be incomplete.

20:41:00 Build Failed. 2 errors, 9 warnings. (took 5m:12s.851ms)
```

I tried to clean and rebuild the workspace but the problem persists.

**UPDATE**

Error messages when building just veins-5.2 in my workspace (with inet-4.4.0 correctly imported and build, but without simu5g)

```
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/puma/omnetpp-6.0/Omnetpp_Projects/veins-veins-5.2/subprojects/veins_inet/src'
MSGC: veins_inet/VeinsInetSampleMessage.msg
veins_inet/VeinsInetSampleMessage.msg:27: Error: cannot resolve import 'inet.common.INETDefs'
veins_inet/VeinsInetSampleMessage.msg:28: Error: cannot resolve import 'inet.common.packet.chunk.Chunk'
veins_inet/VeinsInetSampleMessage.msg:34: Error: 'VeinsInetSampleMessage': unknown base class 'inet::FieldsChunk'
opp_msgtool: error in 1 file(s)
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/puma/omnetpp-6.0/Omnetpp_Projects/veins-veins-5.2/subprojects/veins_inet/src'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:131: veins_inet/VeinsInetSampleMessage_m.h] Error 1
make: *** [Makefile:36: all] Error 2
"make MODE=debug all" terminated with exit code 2. Build might be incomplete.
```

Comment: Simu5G has referenced `veins_inet` but your compiler can't find a way to the shared library. Are you sure you've followed this step from the guide: **Tick the "Search for nested projects" box and select "veins" and "veins_inet" projects. Click Finish.**

Comment: Yes. It definitely is referenced. With just inet-4.4.0 & simu5g in my project workspace, I got no building errors. But when adding veins, it messes up.

Comment: could you compile `veins_inet` alone? is `veins_inet` at the top level of your project (i.e., at the same level as folders with inet, simu5g and veins)? does `veins_inet` correctly reference inet? and how do you compile it? from the IDE?

Comment: As soon as I add veins to the workspace (import from freshly unpacked veins5.2 download, nested projects checked and veins-veins-5.2 & veins_inet selected) I get a "veins_veins-5.2" project. In this project I get subprojects for veins_catch, veins_inet3 & veins_testsims (even though I deselected them while importing) but not veins_inet project. When I delete the veins project, I get asked If I want to delete 1 nested project. If I select no, a veins_inet project is leftover in my workspace. I try to compile from IDE with PROJECT-BUILDALL.

Comment: I also can not build veins alone -  I updated the error messages in my initial post

Answer (score 0):

According to [Veins 5.2 Compatibility](https://veins.car2x.org/download/#compatibility) INET 4.4.0 is not supported by Veins 5.2. Try to use INET 4.3.5.

Comment: it works indeed: http://simu5g.org/simu5g-pnp.html

Comment: In this virtual machine, it is working with these versions. I tried to mimik everything, like ubuntu version, and versions of omnet++, simu5g & veins